# What if a stackful coroutine locks a mutex and then yield?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

If a stackful coroutine locks a mutex (let's first consider a non-recursive mutex) and then yield, when its execution is re-entered, the thread `t2` running it might be different from the previous one before yield `t1`. What will happen, then?

If the mutex is a recursive mutex, `t1` and `t2` who owns the mutex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will just stay locked.

If the ren-enter happens on a different thread, the mutex will just be owned by the wrong thread, leading to UB at best.

Stackless coroutines, on the other hand are just switches in disguise, so if you use lock_guard and similar RAII-enabled containers then there might be excessive lock/unlocking, as well a races when `yield` happens under a lock

Comment: Is there any difference between non-recursive mutex and recursive mutex in this regard?

Comment: Depending on how you use it... Not a lot unless EITHER your coroutine is stackful **and** recursive OR your coroutine is stackless /and/ it does the locking manually. Only with stackless+RAII locks can you afford to resume the coroutine on a different thread.

Comment: FWIW I think _all of these scenarios_ are extremely far-fetched and unlikely. In my experience, Coroutines usually drive a design that avoids shared state and, thus, locking. If there is interaction with external parties then there would only need to be (very) short-lived locks (e.g. used to submit a signal) and never one that's held across yields.

Answer (score 0):

If your application consists of many coroutines (in fact you would use fibers) you should not use mutex's.
instead you could use something like an spinlock utilizing atomics (e.g. the mutex uses internally an spinlock instead of calling into the kernel to suspend the thread if the mutex is locked).

If a coroutine tries to lock this special kind of mutex and the mutex is already locked you could suspend the coroutine and resume another one (== executing other tasks). If the mutex gets unlocked you could resume the suspended coroutine and try to lock the mutex again.

Comment: Good to know. Any spinlock library to recommend?

Comment: boost.fiber implements the stuff you need